# Why Traefik 2.2 & Let's Encrypt does not support new annotations?

Tags: traefik, traefik-ingress

I have setup traefik 2.2 in my self managed kubernetes cluster with Let's Encrypt support.

So far everything works. But the ingress Route configuration in my eyes is still clumsy. It only works if I define two IntgresRoutes - one for HTTP with a redirect middleware to https and one for the https. So my objects look like this:

```
# Middleware for Redirect http -> https
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: https-redirect
spec:
  redirectScheme:
    scheme: https


# IngressRoute http for a simple whoami service
---
kind: IngressRoute
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
metadata:
  name: whoami-notls
  namespace: default

spec:
  entryPoints: 
    - web
  routes:
  - match: Host(`mydomain.foo.com`) 
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: whoami
      port: 8080
    # redirect http to https
    middlewares: 
    - name: https-redirect

# IngresRoute https
---
kind: IngressRoute
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
metadata:
  name: whoami-tls
  namespace: default
spec:
  entryPoints: 
    - websecure
  routes:
  - match: Host(`mydomain.foo.com`) 
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: whoami
      port: 8080
  tls:
    certResolver: default
```

Is there not a more easy way to simply tell traefik that my service - which is listening on port 8080 - should be redirected to HTTPS in any case. Why do I need two separate ingresRoutes in my setup?

In the [announcements](https://containo.us/blog/traefik-2-2-ingress/) for traefik 2.2. there was something like this:

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: foo
  namespace: bar
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: web, websecure
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: redirect-http@kuberntes-crd
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: ""
        backend:
          serviceName: service1
          servicePort: 80
```

It looks very simple. But this did not work for me - traefik is not recognizing this Ingress configuration.

Answer (score 3):

*With the help of the Traefik.io team in [this discussion](https://community.containo.us/t/v2-2-doesnt-create-tls-http-in-kubernetes-ingress-non-crd/5284/5), I now solved the problem:*

To use traefik annotations in Ingress make sure that in your deployment object you have added the ‘kubernetesingress’ provider:

```
...
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - --api
    ....
    - --providers.kubernetescrd=true
    - --providers.kubernetesingress=true
....
```

For a global redirect form HTTP to HTTPS you can also configure this in your traefik deplyoment object:

```
# permanent redirecting of all requests on http (80) to https (443)
- --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure
- --entrypoints.websecure.http.tls.certResolver=default
```

Now you can configure your ingress in an easy way:

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: myingress
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: web, websecure
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.foo.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: whoami
          servicePort: 80
```

See also my latest [Blog post](https://ralph.blog.imixs.com/2020/04/05/traefik-v2-2-and-kubernetes-ingress/).